# How to edit local array from array stored in Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm trying to extract array from Vuex, edit it locally, then:

1. Discard changes without changing the Vuex array, or
2. Submit local changes (to backend).

At this point, editing the local array is also updating the array in Vuex -- which I don't want to.

When I edit the data on the form and return (without submit), the changes are also carried over the the array in Vuex instead of only modifying the local array.

**Quick recap of my code:**

Store:

```
 var app = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        store: new Vuex.Store({
          state: {
            details: [ /* data */ ]
          }
        })
      });
```

HTML:

Note: Here I can see in what the default values are before edit.

```
    <b-form>
     // I'm using the item and index later on
     <div v-for="(item, index) in data">
       // Just want to see what the default values are before editing
       <b-form-input v-model="form.title"></b-form-input>
     </div>
    </b-form>
```

Script:

```
  data() {
    return {
      data: null,
      form: null
    }
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.data = [...this.$store.state.details]
    this.form = this.data[0];
  }
```

How can I improve my code, so that I can make changes locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JSON Parse and Stringify to make a local copy of the Vuex State with no reactivity.

```
  beforeMount() {
    this.data = [...this.$store.state.details]
    this.form = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data[0]));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because it's only clone the array reference and not the objects inside and thats called 'shallow copy', the easiest way to solve this would be to map `details` array and clone the objects inside.

```
this.data = this.$store.state.details.map(i => Object.assign({}, i));
```